# how copy and move files in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: cp, directory-structure

Trying to use the copy move and remove commands in Linux but always get error messages.  There are three symbols in Linux directory structures that I'm having a hard time with  These are ".", "~", and "/".  For example I'd like to copy a file in a directory one level up to someplace do I cp ./filename ~/directory/ . or what.  I'm told I need to include the . to copy it to it's same name.

Yes I've read the manual on cp but this doesn't give specifics.

Comment: this is pretty much the information you need: https://askubuntu.com/questions/232442/how-do-i-navigate-between-directories-in-terminal

Answer (score 2):

To copy a file called `filename` from the current directory to the directory above this directory, you would do

```
cp filename ..
```

The `..` means "the parent directory", and when you don't specify a *filename* for the file at the destination (there's only a directory in the second argument), the file's name will be the same as it already is.

There is no need to use the path-delimiter `/` here, but you *could* have written

```
cp ./filename ../
```

too. Using `./` is a way of explicitly saying "in the current directory".

---

If you want to copy the file from `~/directory` (i.e. from the directory called `directory` in your home directory) to the directory above that directory, then

```
cp ~/directory/filename ~
```

The `~` is a shorthand way of writing the path to you home directory, and the parent directory of `~/directory` is your home directory. The home directory, `~`, may have no relation to either of `.` or `..`, i.e. the current directory (`.`) and the directory above that (`..`) may be some completely different place than your home directory, depending where in the directory structure you've moved with the `cd` command.

Your could also use

```
cp ~/directory/filename ~/directory/..
```

but that would be somewhat awkward to type.

---

To copy a file from the parent directory of the current directory, to some other directory (here `~/directory` as an example):

```
cp ../filename ~/directory
```

Comment: Thanks  this explanation has been quite helpful.

Comment: @NicholasBourbaki Good. You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).

Comment: fyi using `~` is the path to  *whoevers* home directory as specified in `/etc/passwd`.